# How to add wordpress title in php code as a part of alt="" and title=""

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've tried to add a wordpress post title as a part of img alt="" and link title="" in my php code below (place bolded). But I couldn't figure how it should be done.

```
$html .= '<div class="tabela">' .
            '<div class="pozycja">' . $i . '.</div>' .
            '<div class="zdjecie"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="' . $component->link . '" onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Ranking\', \'Home\', \'' . $i . '_Miejsce_Nazwa\');">' . (!empty($photoUrl) ? '<img class="imgskapiec" src="' . $photoUrl . '" alt="**$post-title** ' . $component->name . '">' : '') . '</a></div>' .
            '<div class="nazwa"><a target="_blank" href="' . $component->link . '" rel="nofollow" onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Ranking\', \'Home\', \'' . $i . '_Miejsce_Nazwa\');" title="**$post-title**">' . $component->name . '</a><br /><span style="font-size:11px;">Producent: <strong>'.$producent.'</strong></span></div>' .
            '<div class="link"><a target="_blank" class="linek" href="' . $component->link . '" rel="nofollow" onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Ranking\', \'Home\', \'' . $i . '_Miejsce_Cena\');" title="**$post-title**">Aktualna Cena</a></div>' .
            '</div>';
```

Comment: Please elaborate exactly what you already tried, the question is not very clear.

Comment: In wordpress functions.php theme file I have this part of function:

$html .= '<div class="table">' . **HOW TO ADD WORDPRESS POST NAME HERE** '.$producent.'</div>' .'</div>';
And i wish to add wordpress post name (not post title) in place where "HO TO ADD WORDPRESS POST NAME HERE" is but don't know how. I still get errors (I don't know php much so I don't know how to do it).